# Is it possible to correct my GeoIP location

Tags: services, advertisements, geolocation, geoip

Numerous services and [advertising](http://www.kelvinism.com/tech-blog/i-hate-geoip-advertising/) do GeoIP lookups.  They get the country correct, but often the city is wrong.  Are there places where I can go and correct this, letting people know the actual location of my IP address.  I have a static IP, so it's not going to go to another user in a different location.

Comment: Since you already seem to know where you live, why bother?

Comment: I know companies sell geoip services to advertisers.  I've had the same IP for almost four years, and if I have to see ads, I'd rather they say there's sexy singles in MY suburb, and not the one 20 kms away.

Comment: I would see this as a gift instead of a curse. Online services know way too much about internet users even without pinpointing their exact location from their IP.

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it's possible to correct your GeoIP location. Read on.

There are numerous providers of "Geo IP" data. You first need to figure out which provider the service in question is using, and then file a report/correction with that provider.

I see my location reported incorrectly every time my router gets a new IP. So I usually check my location against various providers using https://www.iplocation.net (click details link next to your IP adddress) which usually flags up one or more services reporting the wrong location.

You can file corrections at the following pages (not a complete list, feel free to *add a comment* with other links, corrections or dead link reports):

- https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-location-correction
- https://db-ip.com/report/
- https://www.home.neustar/resources/tools/submit-to-global-ip-database
- http://www.skyhookwireless.com/submit-access-point
- https://whatismyipaddress.com/location-feedback
- https://ipregistry.co/data-corrections

And some other less friendly reporting methods:

- https://www.ip2location.com/contact/
- http://www.ipligence.com/contact/
- https://ipgeolocation.io/contact.html
- https://support.google.com/websearch/contact/ip/

Answer (score 0):

Matt Sephton's answer is good, but if you are looking to update your IP geolocation with MaxMind, the data correction forms have moved to:

- [Correct your location](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-location-correction)
- [Correct network information](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-isp-org-correction)
- Email correction@maxmind.com to correct other kinds of data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1100737)

Comment: I don't check the links in my answers too often, but I just updated multiple bad or outdated links. If this had been a comment on my answer I'd have rectified the problem immediately.

Comment: Sorry about that, Matt. I haven't really contributed here, so it wasn't meant as a slight against you or anything. I don't really understand all the etiquette or anything yet. Thanks for updating the link.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from changing ISPs (but then it is doubtful whether it would work or not), no.

Answer (score -1):

No.  Your location is probably determined by doing a WhoIs query against your IP block.  Whatever address is listed as owning that IP block is where they are probably getting your "estimated" geographical information.